# Get SqlDataReader instead of RecordSet in Execute SQL task

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I can store my SQL result set into a ADODB record set or ADO.NET recordset. In .NET
I can use a .NET connection manager, get .NET DataSet, extract the DataTable from 
this DataSet and use it. The problem is that I am getting about 30-40K rows in memory.
I don't want to do that. I want to get a SqlDataReader into "some kind of .NET recordset"
so that I can read row by row instead of all at once. How do I do this in ? I want to use C# and .NET only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET has several types of collections List, HashSet ....
All of those will hold the records in memory
DataTable has many features and memory overhead

Create a class with proper properties

```
List<MyClass> MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();

String strSQL = "select * from Table01";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = Cn, CommandText = strSQL };
try
{
    Cn.Open();
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        MyClasses.Add(new MyClass(sdr.GetValue(0));
    }
    sdr.close();       
}
catch (Exception Ex) {}
finally 
{
    Cn.Close();
}
```

30-40K is not all that big unless your row is really big.
I have used collections over 1 million.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process your data row by row and not load it all into memory then why don't you code a custom transformation: Here is something to give you an idea: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136027.aspx

Use your existing connection managers for the source and destination and put a script component in between for your custom row by row processing.

This will process data row by row with the advantage that it uses all of SSIS native ability to shift only the optimal amount of rows into memory buffers (and back out again when not needed)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataReader sdr;
var strSQL = "select * from Table01";
var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = Cn, CommandText = strSQL };
try
{
    sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    sdr.Read();
    if (sdr.HasRows)
    {
        var field = sdr.GetValue(0);
        // and so on....
    }
    dtrContID.Close();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    // .......
}
```

Comment: It is a little late to test for HasRows after the Read.  And this would only read one row.